# C# Winforms DataGridView with sorting/filtering like Ms Excel

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hi I need a quick solution to do filtering/sorting using the Winforms DataGridView control just as in Excel.

I have reviewed the existing posts on this area but none seems to meet my needs.

I am populating my DataGridView manually - no data binding

Comment: DataGridView doesn't support type of filtering out of the box. It will take some work to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480727(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DataGridView columns already support sorting.

I would populate a DataTable with your data and then bind the DataGridView to myDataTable.DefaultView.

You can filter the rows displayed by setting myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter.

You could place Textboxes and/or Comboboxes above the DataGridView and update myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter as the input/selections change.

Comment: Thanks, I have bound to DataTable and I can load my data and do the sorting...
Trying to work on the row filter...
Cheer!!!!

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a Excel like filtering funcionality, check out this article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use a cheap 3rd-party component? Even if you buy it, eventually it could really save your money. [This DataGridView alternative with autofilter](http://10tec.com/winforms-grid/autofilter.aspx) works very fast, and unbound mode is its main work mode. Plus it supports Excel-style AutoFilter.

Comment: because we are programmers. why even bother to program if you can find a software to do that?

Comment: You could re write gcc and every compiler you use too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

[image: Excel Filtering]

[DataGridView-AutoFilter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataGridView-AutoFilter/#) is a ready-made Nuget package, you just need to download it and follow [this](https://anynomous.medium.com/datagridview-autofilter-621f80f71b63) article, it is an easy and enhanced approach.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft has created a sample project](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23459) for VB and C# where they show how to create what they say is an "auto-filter" plugin. I personally do not like it as it allows filter exact only so product and customer will work, open invoice where price > some value is not implemented

Sorting is implemented by using:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in MyDataView.Columns)
{
      column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
}
```

You do this when the grid has it's columns, if auto creating the columns… after binding.