# C#/XAML DataGridView filtering

Tags: c#, xaml, filter, datagridview, filtering

I've been researching on how to get a 'Excel Look-a-Like' filter above the table (DataGridView), but so far I didn't find any possibilities or solutions for this.

**Important information:**

1. The programming language I'm using is '**C#**' or markup language '**XML/XAML**'.
2. I need to get this working in a **WPF** program.
3. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for this scenario

Does anyone know how I can get this done?

On the image below you can see how it should look like:
https://www.mupload.nl/img/f1pm02f61h.png

Thanks in advance for the effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Winforms DataGridView with sorting/filtering like Ms Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239525/c-sharp-winforms-datagridview-with-sorting-filtering-like-ms-excel)

Comment: This question is very broad in scope. Unfortunately, the `DataGridView` does not come with a default “column filter” similar to Excel. Therefore, it appears you will have to create one or look for a third-party library.

Comment: There are good workarounds however one of the linked answers from MSDN:  
[Building a Drop-Down Filter List for a DataGridView Column Header Cell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx) … should give you a good idea of the amount of work involved to create this “Excel” column filter.